# How to change a badge color depending on the value it is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm designing the front-end part of a website using HTML, Bootstrap 3 and jQuery. I want to change the color of a badge depending on the value it was (it will take the value from a database in the future, for now it's on the HTML), but it isn't working right now.

I have this on my HTML file

```
<span class="badge" id = "rating" onload="ratingColor()">Rating: 0/10</span>
```

And this on my js file

```
function ratingColor() {
    var a=document.getElementsById("rating");
    var num=a.charAt(8);
    if(num<5){
        a.className ="badge badge-error";
    }
    else if(num<7 && num>5){
        a.className ="badge badge-warning";
    }
    else{
        a.className ="badge badge-success";
    }
}
```

Why is it not working? It just keeps its grey color. Thank you!

Comment: try invoking the function on demand on your console to check if the function is working ( it should ). I think the issue here is that you run the function onload of the span, that's not a valid event, maybe if you run the function like this: window.onload = function(){ ratingColor(); }

Comment: It is `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

Put the `onload` in a body element, and wrap your element in it.

```js
ratingColor = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById("rating");
  let num = el.innerText.match(/Rating: ([0-9]+)\//)[1];

  if (num < 5) {
    el.className = "badge badge-error";
  } else if (num < 7 && num > 5) {
    el.className = "badge badge-warning";
  } else {
    el.className = "badge badge-success";
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="ratingColor()">
  <span class="badge" id="rating">Rating: 3/10</span>
</body>
```

Or, alternatively, if you need the `onload` applied to only the `<span/>` element, you may do:

```js
ratingColor = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById("rating");
  let num = el.innerText.match(/Rating: ([0-9]+)\//)[1];

  if (num < 5) {
    el.className = "badge badge-error";
  } else if (num < 7 && num > 5) {
    el.className = "badge badge-warning";
  } else {
    el.className = "badge badge-success";
  }
}
document.getElementById("rating").onload = ratingColor();
```

```html
<span class="badge" id="rating">Rating: 3/10</span>
```

Hope that helps,